# Is udp broadcast recorded in the server log?

Tags: udp, firewall, logging

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I've limited network knowledge.

If I sent a string to port 80 on UDP, would the server / receiving IP log it? I'm pretty sure it wouldn't in access logs, but what about firewall logs?

Comment: What exactly is your programming question?

Comment: I'm writing a PHP script that sends data to a random server. Just wanted to know if it logged it in any way.

(This is part of an art project I'm working on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far too general question, thus I'll give a general answer.

In general that would be up to the particular server in use. That is your UDP "Listener" might or might not log incoming traffic as per configuration/settings.
Same applies for your firewall.

Comment: This is a good answer. Whoever gave you -1 is wrong. Fixed ;-)

Comment: @Zepplock. thanks for bringing justice into the court of stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks that helps a lot. You've answered my question there.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of organization you're trying to portscan for your "art project".  If you're targeting a government entity, or Fortune 500 (in which case assume you're going to be prosecuted theft of resources in a court with no understanding of technology) you should assume there will be an intrusion detection system sniffing the network and logging all traffic out of the ordinary.

However if you set up a Windows desktop out of the box, it's not going to log UDP access to closed ports.